# How to setup broadcast factory method in Apache Spark 2

Tags: apache-spark, deprecated, broadcast

In *Apache Spark 1.X*, there was [a configuration setting](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/configuration.html#execution-behavior) named: `"spark.broadcast.factory"` where you could choose a broadcast factory. That setting, seems to be no longer supported in *Apache Spark 2.X* (it's not in the [configurations list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/configuration.html)). How can someone take control of the broadcast factory in *Apache Spark 2.X* ? What's the default broadcast factory? It used to be `TorrentBroadcastFactory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting was removed from 2.X by this commit:
https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/ee8f8d318417c514fbb26e57157483d466ddbfae#diff-c3302615ef6dce00341e156431369d38

See this JIRA for more details about why: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12588 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18742

EDIT: `spark.broadcast.factory` is by default set to `TorrentBroadcastFactory`